# Define comma operator like javascript

Tags: r

Javascript's comma operator is useful for inserting commands within code without it breaking the workflow. The preceding expression is executed but otherwise ignored (e.g. if embedded in a function that is expecting a different object):

```
> x = 5, 4
< 4
> x
< 5
```

Is there any way to implement this in R?  I've tried following

```
',' = function(x, y) { x; y }
```

but R seems to have locked comma down:

```
> 4, 5
Error: unexpected ',' in "4,"
```

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: This works : `','(4, 5)`

Comment: use semicolon `;` instead? i.e. `x = 5; 4` so that its executed but otherwise ignored

Comment: Yeah I guess `{..; ..}` is equivalent. Just fantasised about R having the same elegant method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Un)fortunately `,` is one of the very few things in R that cannot be overloaded/redefined. It’s not an operator in the language, unlike e.g. `` `{` `` and `` `(` ``.

In a similar vein, while you *can* overload `` `=` `` and `` `(` ``, you cannot change their meaning indiscriminately; in a function call with parameters (e.g. `f(a = 1, b = 2)`), neither `(` nor `=` can be made to change their meaning because, once again, they’re not operators in this context).

As noted in the comments, for your purpose, `;` seems to be a very close equivalent, though.